# How to get a list of users who shared a specific post (graph api)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get a user list (just the Facebook user id's) from a specific post on a fanpage?

Searching since a fiew hours but just found FQL- or the deprecated sharer.php stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `POST_ID` to get the details of the shares, just like this-

```
$facebook->api('/POST_ID');
```